# What data structure is returned by Pands.read_excel, and how can I reference the columns of the underlying data frames?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

I am trying to plot columns using Pandas running in Ipython environment with Python 3.4.3. Using the `read_excel` function, I try to convert an xls to a DataFrame as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import pandas as pd  

data=pd.read_excel('/Path/to/file.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1')
print(sup_sub)
```

which results in

```
{'Sheet1':          Day   a   b     c  d
0     Monday  24   1  34.0  3
1    Tuesday   4   7   8.0  2
2  Wednesday   3   6   3.0  1
3   Thursday   2   6   4.0  0
4     Friday   1  34 -11.5 -1
5   Saturday   0   2 -21.0 -2
6     Sunday  -1   4 -30.5 -3}
```

I know this format is incorrect as it doesn't match the formatting when a test excel file is made from scratch; the columns are not properly aligned. This also prevents me from even printing the columns using:

```
print(data.columns)
```

which returns

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'columns'

Is there a simple way to reformat the data so columns can be referenced and graphed?

Answer (score 1):

I think `data` is a dictionary of dataframes, with one entry per sheet of your excel file; you should be able to access the individual dataframes with `data['Sheet1']`.